# How to add categories based on two different variables in SQL Query in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I'm trying to create a data extension that extracts subscriber key and clicks based on specific criteria. Below is the script:

```sql
select c.[JobID]
     , c.[SubscriberKey]
     , c.[URL]
     , j.[EmailName]
     , c.[LinkName]
from [_Click] c
INNER JOIN [_Job] j ON j.[JobID] = c.[JobID]
WHERE j.[EmailName] like '%Onboarding email%'
OR j.[EmailName] IN ('Onboarding3', 'Onboarding4')
AND c.[URL] like '%review%'
OR c.[URL] like '%action%'
OR c.[LinkName] like '%B&I%'
```

This gets me the data that I need which is great. But, I want to add an additional column to my data extension named: **Category**

And I want it to give a category based on the above filters (two different columns), i.e., if **URL** has 'review', then the category is Review. If URL has 'action', then the category is Action. And if the **Link name** has 'B&I', then the category is 'B&I'.

Can someone give me tips on how to go about this? Thank you

Comment: I suspect you are missing some parentheses in your WHERE clause, in order for your logical operators to function as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SQL Case Expression](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_case.asp) to return a value based on a condition.

Try this:

```SQL
SELECT 
  c.[JobID] ,
  c.[SubscriberKey] ,
  c.[URL] ,
  j.[EmailName] ,
  c.[LinkName],
  CASE
    WHEN c.[URL] like '%review%' THEN 'review'
    WHEN c.[URL] like '%action%' THEN 'action'
    WHEN c.[LinkName] like '%B&I%' THEN 'B&I'
    ELSE 'something else'
  END AS Category
FROM [_Click] c
INNER JOIN [_Job] j ON j.[JobID] = c.[JobID]
WHERE j.[EmailName] like '%Onboarding email%'
  OR j.[EmailName] IN ('Onboarding3',
                       'Onboarding4')
  AND c.[URL] like '%review%'
  OR c.[URL] like '%action%'
  OR c.[LinkName] like '%B&I%'
```

Note: I haven't tested on it.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked!